# Generating dummy variable based on two string variables

Tags: stata, string-matching

I want to generate a dummy variable which is 1 if there is any match in two variables. These two variables are generated by `egen concat` and each contains a group of languages used in a country.
For example, `var1` has values of `apc apc apc apc`, and `var2` has values of `apc` or `var1` is `apc fra nya` and `var2` is `apc`. In either cases, `fndmtch2` or `egen anymatch` would not give me 1. Is there anyway I can get 1 for each case?

Comment: It's easier to answer this question if you give an example of your data with `dataex` and your desired outcome.

Comment: What is the definition of "match"? That two variables have a word in common?

Comment: For the examples you give  `gen match = strpos(var1, var2) > 0` is enough to check that the contents of `var2` are included in `var1`.  I'll bet your real data are not so simple but you need to reply to questions in comments from @Wouter and myself to get a fuller answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you both for the comments. So my dataset example is below.
sysuse auto
(1978 automobile data)
. tostring mpg trunk, generate(mpg1 trunk1)
mpg1 generated as str2
trunk1 generated as str2
. egen var1 = concat(mpg1 foreign), punct(" ")
. egen var2 = concat(trunk1 foreign), punct(" ")                    

What I want is to create a variable that is 1 if any word in var1 is included in var2 and any word in var2 is included in var1. In this example, since foreign is common in both var1 and var2, every value for new variable should be 1.

Comment: I followed Nick's suggestion and tried gen match = strpos(var1, var2) > 0, and as Nick mentioned it works for one-way, but what I need is to check in both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data example can be simplified to

```
sysuse auto 
egen var1 = concat(mpg foreign), punct(" ") 
egen var2 = concat(trunk foreign), punct(" ")
```

as mapping to string in this instance is not needed for `mpg trunk` any more than it was needed for `foreign`. `concat()` maps to string on the fly, and the only issues with numeric variables (neither applying here) are if fractional parts are present or you want to see value labels.

Now that it is confirmed that multiple words can be present, we can work with a slightly more interesting example.

Here are two methods. One is to loop over the words in one variable and also the words in the other variable to check if there are any matches.

Stata's definition of a word here is that words are delimited by spaces. That being so, we can check for the occurrence of `" word "` within `" variable "`, where the leading and trailing spaces are needed because in say `"frog toad newt"` neither `"frog"` nor `"newt"` occurs with both leading and trailing spaces. In the OP's example the check may not be needed, but it often is, just as a search for `"1"` or `"2"` or `"3"` finds any of those within `"11 12 13"`, which is wrong if you seek any as a word and not as a single character.

More is said on search for words within strings in a paper in press at the *Stata Journal* and likely to appear in 22(4) 2022.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str8 var1 str5 var2
"FR DE"    "FR"
"FR DE GB" "GB"
"GB"       "FR"
"IT FR"    "GB DE"
end

gen wc = wordcount(var1)
su wc, meanonly 
local max1 = r(max)
replace wc = wordcount(var2)
su wc, meanonly 
local max2 = r(max)
drop wc 

gen match = 0 

quietly forval i = 1/`max1' { 
    forval j = 1/`max2' { 
        replace match = 1 if word(var1, `i') == word(var2, `j') & word(var1, `i') != "" 
    }
}

gen MATCH = 0 

forval i = 1/`max1' { 
    replace MATCH = 1 if strpos(" " + var2 + " ", " " + word(var1, `i') + " ") 
}

list 

     +----------------------------------+
     |     var1    var2   match   MATCH |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. |    FR DE      FR       1       1 |
  2. | FR DE GB      GB       1       1 |
  3. |       GB      FR       0       0 |
  4. |    IT FR   GB DE       0       0 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

EDIT

```
replace MATCH = 1 if strpos(" " + var2 + " ", " " + word(var1, `i') + " ")  & !missing(var1, var2)
```

is better code to avoid the uninteresting match of `"  "` with `"  "`.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the suggestion and your code works for me! I have one follow up question though - is there any way I can control for missing variables for MATCH variable? I think strpos is useful tool but I couldn't figure out how to make it ignore missing values. Currently, MATCH is 1 if either var1 or var2 is missing, but I'd like to make it 0. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed.  Improved code is  above as an EDIT.  Thanks for the error flag.